# Sublime Text 3: Error when converting tabs into spaces

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm getting this error when I try to convert tab into spaces from the menu:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 1066, in run_
    return self.run(edit, **args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 145, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 83, in save_selections
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 83, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 83, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 57, in line_and_normed_pt
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 20, in normed_indentation_pt
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package\indentation.py", line 6, in get_tab_size
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

It happens only on .py files, for example this one:

```
from test import test


class TestClass(App):

    def build(self):
        pass
```

The file is not modified after invoking the conversion.

I've also noted that Tab Width is not set, even though I have set on my config `"tab_size": 4`.

[image]

**Sublime Text Version 3.1.1, Build 3176** running on **Windows 10 Pro**.

Comment: Do you have an example of the pre and post state of the file?

Comment: I've added a simple code example that is giving the error.

Comment: Hm, I am seeing the conversion work both ways. Can you spot check if the number of spaces is consistent throughout indentations? If you haven't changed your setting, the number of spaces (4) and the tab size (4) should be displayed at the bottom right of the window when you convert.

Comment: Seems like the tab size is not being loaded, even though I have the configuration on my settings.

Comment: You can also try manually doing this by using the find and replace function. I would copy a tab from your file, and using the function replace it with 4 spaces typed out manually.

Comment: What output do you get in the Sublime console if you focus a Python file that exhibits this behavior and then enter `view.settings().has("tab_size")`? My guess is that it will say `True`, which would be an indication that either you have Python specific settings that are setting it to `null` or a plugin has clobbered the setting out.

Comment: Says `True` indeed. I'll try later by uninstalling some packages.

Comment: I've removed all the packages, uninstalled and installed the app again and it's still giving the same error. Only after I select the `Tab Width` from the UI, it works.